# GStreamer 1.0 (gst-omx) does not show jpeg images

Tags: raspbian

I try to play/show a jpeg image using gstreamer1.0 (gstreamer1.0-omx), but the picture is not shown at all. Videos however are played wittout problems. I there anything has to be set for displaying images?

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ gst-launch-1.0 -v playbin uri=file:///home/pi/media/1_Zug_10s.jpg 
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: ring-buffer-max-size = 0
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: buffer-size = -1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: buffer-duration = -1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: use-buffering = false
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: download = false
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: uri = file:///home/pi/media/1_Zug_10s.jpg
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: connection-speed = 0
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: source = "\(GstFileSrc\)\ source"
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind.GstPad:src: caps = "image/jpeg\,\ width\=\(int\)1920\,\ height\=\(int\)1080\,\ sof-marker\=\(int\)0"
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstOMXMJPEGDec-omxmjpegdec:omxmjpegdec-omxmjpegdec0.GstPad:sink: caps = "image/jpeg\,\ width\=\(int\)1920\,\ height\=\(int\)1080\,\ sof-marker\=\(int\)0"
```

I'm using raspbian jessie, boot to console. gpu_mem=128 is set in config.txt.